# How to wait the return of a Callback function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

How to implement that use case properly:
after the customer has confirmed an action I want to display a waiting screen until the callback function has been performed completely...

I've done the following but the REST call is performed after that the `srv.hideLoadingScreen()` has been called... :-/

**DialogService:**

```
srv.onApprove = function(callback){
    srv.displayLoadingScreen();
    callback();
    srv.hideLoadingScreen();
};
```

**Controller:**

```
ctrl.showConfirmModal = function(){
    //...
    if(approved){
        DialogService.onApprove(function(){
            ctrl.performAction();
        });
    }
};

ctrl.performAction = function(){
    console.log('performAction');
    if(angular.isDefined(ctrl.selectedNumberList)){
        var numberList = {
            nbList: ctrl.selectedNumberList
        };
        MyService.launch(numberList, function(response){ // REST call
            console.log('call ok');
        }, function(error){
            console.log('error');
        });
    }
};
```

---

**Update:**
Currently I've chose this solution that avoids a *callback* of the *callback*:
Close the waiting panel in the `ctr.perfomAction()`

```
MyService.launch(numberList, function(response){ // REST call
    console.log('call ok');
    DialogService.hideLoadingScreen();
}, function(error){
    console.log('error');
    DialogService.hideLoadingScreen();
});
```

Comment: You need to hide the loading screen inside the callback...

Comment: or have a callback in your callback :P

Comment: If your callback is doing something asynchronous then you also need a callback from that, or pass a callback function anonymously.

Comment: @epascarello: it was my first idea to do `DialogService.hideLoadingScreen()` beside the two `console.log()` in the service... but it implies to do that in every callback function :-(

Comment: Or you use promises...

Comment: Not for that use case.

Comment: What else do you need help with?

Comment: I've chosen to uncouple these two screens in order to leave the control to the main controller. and that one will start itself the `displayLoadingScreen()` when it's needed & close it after...

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [the `$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to return a Promise.

Asynchronous actions aren't returned until they are completed and the call stack is clear. Since we'll leave scope before they are returned you can use a Promise to ensure you get the value back.

```
app.service('MyService', function($http) {
  this.launch = function launch() {
    return $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/endpoint' });
  };
}

app.controller('MyCtrl', function(MyService) {
  MyService.launch()
     .then(function(response) {

     });
});
```

The same can also be achieved with the `$q` service to return a promise for any type asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Angular-busy](https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy).
This way should work for you:

***APPLY***

1. `bower install angular-busy --save`
2. Add [dist/angular-busy.js](https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy/blob/master/dist/angular-busy.js) and [dist/angular-busy.css](https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy/blob/master/dist/angular-busy.css) to your
   `index.html`
3. Add `cgBusy` as a module dependency for your module.
4. `angular.module('your_app', ['cgBusy']);`

***CONTROLLER***

```
   $scope.myPromise = MyService.launch(numberList, function(response){ // REST call...
```

***PARTIAL***

```
        <div cg-busy="{promise:myPromise,
                       message:'Loading',
                       backdrop:false,
                       templateUrl:'myAwesomeTemplate.html',
                       delay:300,
                       minDuration:700} ">
         </div>
```

***EDIT FOR YOUR COMMENT:***

What about something like this?

```
 MyService.launch(numberList, function(response){
  ----->     $scope.myPromise = console.log('call ok');     <--------
        }, function(error){
            console.log('error');
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately the callback function isn't always a function that returns a promise and your lib needs it for working properly...